# How to add request on Jboss restart?

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

It is possible to send a request from Jboss (Wildfly 10.1.0) to connected database on start/restart? To be more specific I want to clear some tables on restart.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a startup EJB in your application.

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class MyStartupBean {

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // clear the tables
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's one of possibilities, but I want something other, more on server-side than on application-side

Comment: There is nothing that you could use on server side. What don't you like with this solution?

Comment: I need to use that request only on one server, but I've got 3 instances

Comment: With two different datasources

Comment: then you have to do kind of locking on the database that only one instance can clear the tables.